# Does the fundamental group of the normalization of a scheme inject into the fundamental group of the scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, fundamental-group

Let $X$ be an integral noetherian finite type scheme over an algebraically closed  field $k$. Let $X'\to X$ be its normalization. Is the induced homomorphism of etale fundamental groups $\pi_1(X')\to\pi_1(X)$ injective?

If so, does this correspond to the fact that the functor Fet(X) $\to $ Fet(X') is fully faithful?

Comment: Full faithfulness corresponds to surjections of fundamental groups (not injections), cf. e.g. [Tag 0BN6](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BN6).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both questions have negative answers.  Begin with $\mathbb{P}^4$.  Let $L\subset \mathbb{P}^4$, resp. $\Pi\subset \mathbb{P}^4$, be a line, resp. $2$-plane, and assume that $L$ and $\Pi$ are disjoint.  Let $C\subset \Pi$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $g>0$.  Let $f:C\to L$ be a finite morphism.  Let $X$ be the union over all $t\in C$ of $\text{span}(t,f(t))\subset \mathbb{P}^4$.  Then $X$ is simply connected.  Yet $X'$ is a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle over $C$, hence it has fundamental group equal to the fundamental group of $C$.

To see that $X$ is simply connected, observe that both $L$ and every $\text{span}(t,f(t))$ are connected and simply connected.  Thus, for every finite, étale morphism $u:Y\to X$, the curve $u^{-1}(L)$ is a disjoint union of copies of $L$.  Fix one such copy, say $L_i$. For every $t\in C$, the curve $u^{-1}(\text{span}(t,f(t)))$ is also a disjoint union of copies of $\text{span}(t,f(t))$.  There is precisely one such copy that intersects $L_i$.  The union over all $t\in C$ of this copy of $\text{span}(t,f(t))$ is a copy of $X.$

**Edit.** An "official" reference for the argument in the second paragraph is Corollaire IX.6.11 of the following.

MR0217088 (36 #179b) 
Grothendieck, Alexander
Revêtements étales et groupe fondamental. Fasc. II: Exposés 6, 8 à 11. 
 
Séminaire de Géométrie Algébrique, 1960/61. Troisième édition, corrigée 
 
Institut des Hautes Études Scientifiques, Paris 1963 i+163 pp.

There is a unique morphism $F:X\to L$ whose restriction to $X\setminus L$ is the composition of projection to $C$ followed by $f$.  This morphism is projective and surjective.  The fibers are connected and étale simply connected (a union of concurrent lines).  Thus, by the Corollaire, $X$ is also étale simply connected.